# Speed up Google Maps rendering

Tags: google-maps, optimization, rendering

What does the Google Maps rendering speed depends on and what are the best ways to optimize it ?

In that question we assume that there is no issue regarding the internet connection / browser... It's more of a general case on how to optimize the rendering.

The rendering of Google Maps is done in a website (mydomain.com).

Comment: By "rendering speed", do you mean the speed it takes for the Google Maps API script to load, the amount of time it takes for the map to display, the amount of time it takes the map to draw tiles, or the amount of time it takes to display custom data on the map?